# Cakephp CASE WHEN argument in find conditions

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

How would you put below in the find field option?

```
CASE WHEN User.id = $user_id
  THEN 0 
  ELSE 1  END as user_sort
```

I tried putting this inside 'fields' array but the result does not seem to come out.

Is there a way we can put this inside fields array so I can pass in my $user_id argument?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this page](http://cakephp.1045679.n5.nabble.com/How-to-use-MySql-s-CASE-WHEN-function-with-CakePhp-td1259636.html), you can do it like this:

```
$this->Something->find('all', array( 
   'fields' => array( 
       'Something.id', 
       '((CASE WHEN Something.id%2=0 THEN \'even\' ELSE \'odd\' END)) AS parity' 
   ) 
));
```